# Android: New styles in `pt` or `sp`?

Tags: android

I'm in the process of replacing the font in our Android app.
For that purpose got the definitions in Zeplin from my designer which have assigned font sizes in `pt`.

I've defined some new styles where I'm converting those `pt` values to `sp` using an [online converter](https://pixplicity.com/dp-px-converter/).

The resulted `sp` values are decimal so my question is: If I drop the conversion and define the size in `pt`, would Android necessarily auto-convert this to `sp`, or do I NEED to define in `sp` no matter how much "ugly" the `sp` value is?

Example:

```
<style name="new_font_action_button_label">
    <item name="android:textSize">33.33sp</item> <!--15pt-->
    <item name="variant">medium</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:spacing">0.49sp</item>
</style>
```

I know I can round the values, but still...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely neither. I recommend you first  understand what these units are and why are different and not equivalent (docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension). Once you got that step done you probably figure out yourself that unless your UI is fully scallable then using `sp` for everything makes very little sense. The next step will be figuring out what will be your designer's working reference dpi (`xxdpi` or higher) and you are mostly done.